# Grails extJS grid paging

Tags: grails, extjs

Hy, I have a problem with extjs and grails.
When I a try call the next page of the grid, I don't have the objects.
The grid still with the old objects.
How can I do to paginate my grid?

Answer (score 0):

add below to your store cfg:

```
paramNames: {start:'offset',limit:'max',sort:'sort',dir:'order'},
baseParams: {offset:0,max:this.pageSize},
```

then the controller:

```
def result = Floor.createCriteria().list(
   max:params.int('max')?:100, 
   offset:params.int('offset')?:0
) 
render ([count:result.totalCount,data:result] as JSON)
```